# Weak derivative of a function that is continuously differentiable except a finitely many points.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I want to prove that, if $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable except at $x_1,\dots, x_m$, where it is discontinuous, then
$$f'=\frac{df}{dx}+\sum_{i=1}^m[f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)]\delta_{x_i}.$$

Of course the LHS is the weak derivative but I don't really know what is meant by $\frac{df}{dx}$ is this context since $f$ is not $C^1(\mathbb{R})$. How do I go about this?
Of course I'm trying to proceed by the definition of weak derivative but don't really know how to proceed.
My work
\begin{align}\langle\frac{df}{dx}+\sum_{i=1}^m[f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)]\delta_{x_i},\varphi\rangle&=\langle\frac{df}{dx},\varphi\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^m[f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)]\langle\delta_{x_i},\varphi\rangle\\
&=\langle\frac{df}{dx},\varphi\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^m[f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)]\varphi(x_i)\end{align}

but I have no idea how to construct $-\langle f,\varphi'\rangle$ from this.

Comment: Start from $<f,\phi’>$ and break the integral into a sum of integrals over the smaller sub intervals. Now integrate by parts on each term to bring the derivative onto $f$. The boundary terms become your delta functions

Comment: @NickAlger what does $df/dx$ mean then in this context? Any function that extends the derivative to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes the argument will hold nomatter what value you put into df/dx at those points. You may also simply define elements of a function space as equivalence classes of functions that agree almost everywhere. This is commonly how Sobolev spaces are defined

Comment: How do you know the jumps at each $x_i$ are finite in height? The function $f(x):= 1/x$ for $x \neq 0$ with $f(0):=0$ seems fits the hypothesis, but the corresponding coefficient of $\delta$ on the RHS of your formula is an indeterminate form.

Comment: @giobrach I think the OP probably means that $f\in C^1([ x_i , x_{i+1}]) $ for each $i$ or maybe $C^0([ x_i , x_{i+1}]) \cap C^1((x_i , x_{i+1}))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x_k<x_{k+1}$, i.e. the terms are in increasing order. Assume that $f$ is $C^1$ on the open intervals, $(-\infty,x_1)$, $(x_m,+\infty)$, and $(x_k,x_{k+1})$ for all $k=1,\dots,m-1$, and that $f$ is continuous on the closed intervals $(-\infty,x_1]$, $[x_m,+\infty)$, and $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ for all $k=1,\dots,m-1$.

To explain the noation, on the left hand side the function $f$ has been identified with the distribution $T_f$ given by $$\langle T_f ,\varphi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \varphi (x) $$ for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R)$. Then $f'$ means the distributional derivative of $T_f$. Now on the right hand side, $\frac{df}{dx}$ simply means the usual pointwise derivative of $f$ - there's no issue with this since $f$ is differentiable everywhere except on $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ which has measure zero in $\mathbb R$.

Now to answer your question, recall that distributional derivative $T'$ of a distribution $T$ is, by definition, given by $\langle T', \varphi \rangle = - \langle T,\varphi'\rangle $. Hence, for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R)$,

\begin{align*}
\langle f',\varphi \rangle = \langle T_f', \varphi \rangle &= - \langle T_f,\varphi'\rangle \\
&=- \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx \\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx -\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx -\int_{x_m}^{+\infty} f(x) \varphi'(x) \, dx
\end{align*} Next, we will integrating by parts on each interval. Note that  $\varphi$ has compact support so the terms at $\pm \infty$ vanish and $f$ is possible discontinuous across each $x_k$, so we need to keep a track of which direction we approach from (notated by $f(x_k^+)$ and $f(x_k^-)$:  \begin{align*}
\langle f', \varphi \rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \varphi(x) \frac{df}{dx}(x)  \, dx -f(x_1^-)\varphi(x_1) \\
&\qquad +\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \bigg [  \int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}  \varphi(x) \frac{df}{dx}(x) \, dx  -f(x_{k+1}^-)\varphi(x_{k+1}) + f(x_k^+)\varphi(x_k)\bigg ]  \\
&\qquad +\int_{x_m}^{+\infty}  \varphi(x) \frac{df}{dx}(x) \, dx+ f(x_m^+)\varphi(x_m).
\end{align*} Then expand the brackets and change dummy variable for the terms involving $f(x_{k+1}^-)\varphi(x_{k+1})$ to get\begin{align*}
\langle f', \varphi \rangle 
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\varphi(x) \frac{df}{dx}(x) \, dx +\sum_{k=1}^m \big ( f(x_k^+)-f(x_k^-)\big )\varphi(x_k)\\
&= \bigg \langle \frac{df}{dx} + \sum_{k=1}^m \big ( f(x_k^+)-f(x_k^-)\big )\delta_{x_k}, \varphi \bigg \rangle 
\end{align*} using that $\langle \delta_a , \varphi \rangle = \varphi(a)$. Hence, $$f' =\frac{df}{dx} + \sum_{k=1}^m \big ( f(x_k^+)-f(x_k^-)\big )\delta_{x_k}.$$